# Calling printf from assembly - not working

Tags: c, assembly

Well.. i've tried a few things but I can't get this to work.

How do I push the address of `_hello` correctly for the `printf()` function?

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.extern printf

.global printf2

_hello: .ascii  "Hello World!\0"

printf2:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push _hello
    call _printf

    pop ebp
    ret
```

With "*not working*" I mean that the program simply crashes.

Comment: Aren't you missing an `add esp,4` after the call to `_printf`?

Comment: @Michael: Yes but that's not the core problem.

Comment: You are not cleaning up the stack properly after calling `_printf`. Thus, `pop ebp` moves an invalid value into `ebp`.

Comment: Hmm, actually my answer may be wrong. I missed that OP is using `intel_synatx` (uhg). If so I'll delete it.

Comment: here I was thinking multiple things were wrong, including the potential for the `printf` in question being fast call and requiring register-setup of the first N arguments. I really need to switch back to caffeinated beverages in the morning.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Do I have to clean the stack for `_printf`?

Comment: @StefanFalk : No, after `_printf`, assuming that you're using the standard SysV i386 ABI calling sequence for it. A simple `add esp, 4` will do the trick.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar unfortunatelly it doesn't work? I placed it right after `call _printf`

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I really don't get it why it's not working ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not identify which OS you use.

This is correct for MinGW-GAS for Windows:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.extern _printf
.global _printf2

_hello: .ascii  "Hello World!\0"

_printf2:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push OFFSET _hello
    call _printf
    add esp, 4

    pop ebp
    ret
```

And this one is for Linux-GAS:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.extern printf
.global printf2

_hello: .ascii  "Hello World!\0"

printf2:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push OFFSET _hello
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    pop ebp
    ret
```

Consider the different use of the underscores!

Comment: Thank you very much I really was questioning all my years of studying computer science at this point.. but it was just the `OFFSET` instruction that was missing!

Comment: Do you know where I can find a useful reference for the MinGW-GAS ?

Comment: @StefanFalk: I haven't found a useful reference for `.intel_syntax` yet. In doubt I try MASM-Syntax as it was right in this case.